# node.js server running but not loading

Tags: windows, node.js

I've just installed node.js on my computer running Win7(64bit).

The problem is that when I run a simple hello-world application it is running (as confirmed by  `console.log()` and me pushing the code to OpenShift where it works just fine) but when I try to load the page in `localhost:1337` it just keeps on loading (eventually times out).

I've no idea what to check, since firewall is *not* blocking node and I'm not running anything that would block the port.

Here's the server code.

```
#!/bin/env node
// Include http module.
var http = require("http");
//Get the environment variables we need if on OpenShift
var ipaddr = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 1337;

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   request.on("end", function () {
      response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });
      response.end('Hello HTTP!');
   });
}).listen(port, ipaddr);

console.log('It works');
console.log('IP : ' + ipaddr + '\nPort : ' + port);
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

*edit*

Here's a screenshot of commandline output.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGaLD.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node server is hanging as you need to always call `response.end`.

I believe that listening to the [end](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_2) event on the `request` is causing the timeout. If you remove it will work.

Comment: Heh, indeed! This fixed the problem, thank you. I am puzzled, though, why it worked when I tested it on OpenShift?

Comment: @user2978301 I am not familiar with OpenShift but this works because the browser does not close the connection hence the `end` event never fires